Meaning of words "in" and "out" in Kotlin generics
I learn kotlin generics but naming makes me crazy.
Let consider 2 code snippets in java and in Kotlin which do the same job:
1. java
    public void copy(List<? extends Number> from, List<? super Number> to) {
        assert from.size() == to.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < from.size(); ++i) {
            to.add(from.get(i));
        }
    }

Everything is clear.
from is a list of items of type which inherits from Number. So it could be List<Double> List <Short> etc. I understand why extends word is used
to is a list of items of type which is a supertype of Number. So it could List<Number> or List<Serializable> or List<Object>
2.Kotlin
The similar code for Kotlin:
    fun copy(from: Array<out Number>, to: Array<in Number>) {
        assert(from.size == to.size)
        for (i in from.indices)
            to[i] = from[i]
    }

From my point of view it looks counterintuitive.
Why Array<out Number> is Array of subtypes of Number ?
Why Array<in Number> is Array of supertypes of Number ?
I am sure creaters had some logic and I want to understand it.

I guess this is a matter of taste. For me after using the Java for 15 years, it is still confusing which one to use. I understand it, I just need to think twice, the third time and forth time if what I do is really what I need. in/out was for me like: "oh, so it could be THAT simple?".

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html

Java PECS: Producer extends, Consumer super. Kotlin in/out: out is some that produces things, that you can get things out of; in is something you can put things in.

Array<out Number> is an array you can get Numbers out of.
Array<in Number> is an array you can put Numbers in to.
This is the core of how you should be thinking about it, and specifically why those names make sense.  For what exactly the relevant types are -- when you think about "what sort of array can I get Numbers out of, you will notice that you can certainly get Numbers out of an Array<Int> or an Array<Double>, and conclude that any type that extends Number is a valid type argument for Array<out Number>.  Additionally, you can certainly put any Number into an Array<Object>, and deduce that an Array<in Number> is an Array<T> where T is some supertype of Number.
In general, however, Kotlin just switches from "what could this type be?" which List<? extends Number> makes clearer, to "what can I do with this type?" which MutableList<in Number> makes clearer.

Adding to the great answer by @Louis Wasserman and explaining why the change:
If you ever need to describe parameters of your copy function to your friend, would you rather say:

I need one array of numbers for reading and another array of numbers for writing.

Or something like:

I need one array of numbers or their subclasses and another array of numbers or their superclasses

First sounds like speaking to a human. Second sounds like speaking to a compiler.
For me personally, extends/super feel like a result of my design choices. in/out is the design choice itself.
One thing that may be potentially confusing about in/out is that depending on our perspective, we can argue in should be for covariance and out for contravariance. Ambiguity comes from the fact that we can look at this from two different sides of the communication. For example: "We consume items from this object" (InputStream). "This object consumes items" (in variance).
